# NoReverseMatch Reverse for 'my_url' not found

Tags: python, django

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from . import views
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.conf import settings
from .views import Search

app_name = 'base'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^index/$', Search.as_view(), name='index'),
    url(r'^newresume/$', views.newresume, name='newresume'),
    url(r'^profile/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.profile, name='profile'),
    url(r'^update_info/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.update_info, name='update_info'),
]
```

views.py

```
def profile(request, pk):
    student = get_object_or_404(Students, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'base/profile.html', {'student': student})
```

_tweet_search.html

```
<div class="studentfio">
    <a href="{% url 'profile' pk=student.pk %}"><h4>{{ student.job }}</h4></a>
</div>
```

[Console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nltrK.png)

Hi all, help me with this error, please. I made a AJAX-request, after this i get an error, how can i fix that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="studentfio">
    <a href="{% url 'base:profile' student.pk %}"><h4>{{ student.job }}</h4></a>
</div>
```

as you have mentioned `app_name` in your `urls.py` file, you need to mention that in your `url`